# Why my R studio is not displaying box plots?

Tags: r, boxplot

After executing my below code Plots are not displaying, especially when I add required libraries even also the plots are not displaying in plots pane.

```
#install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
library(readr)
#get pwd
getwd()
#set pwd
setwd("/home/karthik_ksk/")
getwd()
mydir="R work"
myfiles <- list.files(path=mydir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles
#dat_csv = ldply(myfiles, read_csv)
#dat_csv
#read_csv(misfiles[1])
#read_csv(myfiles[2])
read_csv(myfiles[6])
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#library("tidyverse") 
library(ggplot2)
names(myfiles) <- list.files(mydir, "*.csv")
input <- myfiles[6][,c('state_code','population')]
print(input)
jpeg(file= "boxplot_test.jpeg")
boxplot(state_code ~ population, data=input, xlab = "statecode", ylab = "population", main = "testdata")
dev.off()
options(device = "RStudioGD")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. A reproducible example would be helpful, containing the bare minimum code that others could run. Say you used some fake data or an inbuilt data set like **mtcars** - would that work?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of your boxplot code is in between the function jpeg() and dev.off(). That means that you opened a device with the function jpeg(), made the boxplot and closed it with dev.off(). So, your figure must be in the working directory, and it's not shown in the plots pane.